# IRF740 datasheet. Error in the datasheet or I'm interpreting it wrong?

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

According to the [IRF740 data-sheet from IR](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf740.pdf) or [from Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/docs/91054/91054.pdf) (they are nearly the same, the Vishay is better to read), the **Qg** is specified as **63nC** under **Id = 10A** **Vds = 320V** and **Vgs = 10V**.

But at *page 4, Fig. 6 - Typical Gate Charge vs. Drain-to-Source Voltage*, The graph shows that under the same conditions the **Qg** is **~45nC**. Its **63nC** at a **Vgs = ~15V**.

Is the data-sheet that have a error or I'm interpreting it wrong?

[image: Typical Gate Charge vs. Drain-to-Source Voltage graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you're interpreting it wrong. The 63 nC is a *maximum* figure, while your graph shows *typical* Qg - which is, as you might expect, less than the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

The value in the table is a maximum value.

The curve in the chart is a typical characteristic.

The charts almost always show typical values, not specification limits.

> I assumed the graph showed the maximum value too

[image]

Comment: As it generally better to dimension the gate-drive for the worst case, I assumed the graph showed the maximum value too. Anyway that's just talking about the data-sheet, thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's on page 3, the title of the section of the datasheet that contains all the charts is "Typical Characteristics".

Comment: Yes, even that's only present at the Vishay datasheet, the graph itself says "**Typical** Gate Charge vs. Drain-to-Source Voltage".

Comment: As the graph seems linear above certain **Vgs** (but this is a so dynamic property), would interpolating between the max/typical value at **Vgs = 10V** to get the maximum value at **Vgs = 15V** or some common safety margin?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento 1. You say " ...Yes, even that's only present at the Vishay datasheet, ..."-> NO both data sheets make it clear what is max and what is typical. 2. Also, graphs are always typical unless stated otherwise. 3. This is engineering !!!!!!!!!!! 45 = = 63 = = 50 == 45 ==70. ie you are extremely unlikely to have to have the sort of precision you are aiming at in Q.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon 1. "the title of the section of the datasheet" not the individual graph title 2. As I said I don't know that, is that something you can't tolerate? 3. I don't asked for high precision just the worst case or max value for the **Qg**, as this could make the turn-off time crosses the boundary of the dead-time in the driver IC making shot-thought in half-bridge.